# Converting Screen to Client coordinate issues

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a control called RackViewer that contains another control called ItemViewer within it. The RackViewer control is dynamically added to another parent control. Within the parent control, I wish to create a drag drop event such that when the user would be dragging an item over the ItemViewer control within the RackViewer, the event would fire. Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
private void RackView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    RackViewer rackView = (RackViewer)sender;
    if (rackView.IsMouseOnItemViewer(rackView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))))
    {
        //content goes here
    }
}

private void RackView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    RackViewer rackView = (RackViewer)sender;
    if(rackView.IsMouseOnItemViewer(rackView.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y))))
    {
        //content goes here
    }
}

private void listbox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox dragDropSender = (ListBox)sender;
    int index = dragDropSender.IndexFromPoint(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        dragDropSender.SelectedIndex = index;
        dragDropSender.DoDragDrop(dragDropSender.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}
```

Note the IsMouseOnItemViewer method. This method is contained in the rackViewer class and confirms that the user is dragging the item over the ItemViewer before proceeding with the drag drop event sequence. The reason I do this is because I don't have access to the ItemViewer from the parent control of RackViewer since it is 2 controls higher in the hierarchy. The "IsMouseOnItemViewer" method looks like this:

```
    public ItemViewer View { get {return itemViewer; } }

/// <param name="mousePoint"> The coordinates of the mouse in client coordinates. </param>
    /// <returns> True if the user is hovering over the ItemViewer control and false otherwise.</returns>
    public bool IsMouseOnItemViewer(Point mousePoint)
    {
        if (View.Bounds.Contains(mousePoint))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

However, for some reason this event never returns true! No matter where I would drag the mouse over the RackViewer control, it seems to never detect that it is over the ItemViewer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried debugging or tracing the `mousePoint` and `View.Bounds` to see they are really what you expect? View.Bounds are coordinates relative to the parent of ItemViewer. Are you sure that `mousePoint` is also relative to the parent of ItemViewer? is rackView parent of ItemViewer instance?

Comment: Yes the parent control ItemViewer is RackViewer as its positioned directly on the RackViewer in the designer. I assume that doing rackViewer.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y)) would have converted the mouse point from screen coordinates to coordiantes relative to RackViewer? I'm having a bit of trouble debugging since the DragEnter even launches right as I enter the RackViewer and thus I would of course not have the correct coordinates yet.

Comment: yes, it should have. I would log the coordinates and check the values.

Comment: are you sure that Drag events go to RackViewer. Could it be that ItemViewer swallows them so RackViewer is not called?

Comment: What do you mean? I assign the dragdrop event handlers to rackViewer and during debugging I can see that the event is fired when I drag an item over the rackViewer

Comment: yes, but if `ItemView.AllowDrop == true` then when the mouse enters ItemView it will take over the drag notifications, and RackView will not be notified.

Comment: Ok I found the error. My issue was that the dragEnter event only fires once and it fires right as the mouse drags the item over the rackviewer. Thus, the mouse will never have time to actually reach the ItemViewer. Thanks for your help. I'm going to have to use something more dynamic than DragEnter

Comment: have you tried DragOver?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the error. My issue was that the dragEnter event only fires once and it fires right as the mouse drags the item over the rackviewer. Thus, the mouse will never have time to actually reach the ItemViewer. Thanks for your help. I'm going to have to use something more dynamic than DragEnter.